# Summernote получить текст с форматированием

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Есть текст с форматированием: "***TEST***".
Получаю выделенный текст с помощью `$(element).summernote('createRange');`
Отдает: "TEST" без форматирования. Как можно получить этот же текст, но только уже с форматированием?

Answer (score -2):

Тогда нужно брать не текст, а HTML.

```
$(element).html();
```

Comment: нужно взять именно выделенный текст, а не всё из редактора